# Image border using CSS or Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

Can i give an image with an effect like

http://wfs-01.wapka.mobi/300036/300036239_0f906fc5ce.png

And the image will be inside that border. Is there any way i can implement in any language like **jquery**, **javascript** or **CSS**?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: @JosephSilber i dont know whether it can be done. Just need some tips if it can be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSS transforms](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transforms/) can do the trick in modern browsers.

Here's a [demo](https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/perspective-by-example.html). And [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform)'s documentation from MDN.

Comment: What about the tilt? The image provided has a shift on the z-axis

Comment: @djthoms It could be done by setting a proper perspective value and applying a `rotateY` transform to the image element.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 Transitions, Transforms, Animation, Filters and more!

Have a look at [this](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/)